# Implement algorithm for finding reference records

Tags: java

I want to implement in Java algorithm which finds all records with reference id:

```
| id | unique_id | reference_id |   |   |
|----|-----------|--------------|---|---|
| 43 | 55544     |              |   |   |
| 45 | 45454     | 43           |   |   |
| 66 | 55655     | 45           |   |   |
| 78 | 88877     | 66           |   |   |
| 99 | 454       | 33           |   |   |
```

Expected result for record with unique_id 55544:

```
| id | unique_id | reference_id |   |   |
|----|-----------|--------------|---|---|
| 43 | 55544     |              |   |   |
| 45 | 45454     | 43           |   |   |
| 66 | 55655     | 45           |   |   |
| 78 | 88877     | 66           |   |   |
```

This is the solution with this SQL query:

```
select @ref:=id as id, unique_id, reference_id
from mytable
join (select @ref:=id from mytable WHERE unique_id = 55544)tmp
where reference_id=@ref
```

I tried this Java code:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> get(@PathVariable String id) {

        Optional<PaymentTransactions> obj = transactionService.findById(Integer.parseInt(id));

        List<PaymentTransactions> finalList = new ArrayList<PaymentTransactions>();

        PaymentTransactions tnx = obj.get();

        int ref_id = 0;

        while(obj != null) {

            List<PaymentTransactions> ref_list = transactionService.findByReference_transaction_id(ref_id);
            ref_id = ref_list.get(0).getReference_transaction_id();

            finalList.addAll(ref_list);
        }

        return finalList;
    }
```

I tried this code but it's not working. What is the proper wya to implement this Java code?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. You say you want all entries with reference ID yet in your example, you show that an entry without reference ID should be returned?

Comment: I take it you mean getting all records in a hierarchy. I'd be looking to do this with recursive queries and CTE's. 
I've done this with SQL-Server and Oracle in the past (both have their own nuances). 
Hence, you should have tagged the question with the DB you are using too.
https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/24/sql-server-introduction-to-hierarchical-query-using-a-recursive-cte-a-primer/
https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/recursive-subquery-factoring-11gr2
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL

Comment: You can return results depth or breadth first too. Can include depth from root as a column in your results and read resultset sequentially afterwards.

Comment: Please post [mcve] including some hard-coded test data.